# "Another program Busy" dialog using ActiveX control in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, mfc, activex

I am using ActiveX control in VC++ to work with com-port equipment (scales). Here is the code:

```
IScale * objsc;
CoInitialize(NULL);
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Scale, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IScale, (void**)&objsc);
objsc->Connect(port, 1000);
objsc->UpdateOnlyWeight();
```

When the scales connected properly, everything is OK. But when there is some problem with connection I receive "Another program Busy" dialog, and the only way to shut down the whole program is to kill the process. The dialog appears during objsc->UpdateOnlyWeight(); Function objsc->Connect(port, 1000); does not return a value, so I can not ensure, if the connection was successful. So the question is, how can I prevent the appearing of "Another program Busy" dialog, and catch an error when the scales did not connected properly.

Comment: Contact the author of the ActiveX control. Since we don't know, what ActiveX control you are using, there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: There is no contacts of the author. May be I can use some sort of timeout for UpdateOnlyWeight() function< and kill it when it did not respond for a second?

Comment: The ActiveX control is obviously buggy. Only the author of the ActiveX control can fix that. Since you aren't sharing information on the specific ActiveX control you are using, I'm voting to close this question.